# Suppress "Back Button" event when clicking an image in a css gallery

Tags: html, css

I am using a css gallery very much alike this one(or at least I took the idea of it, but problem is the same):
https://codepen.io/huijing/pen/GvNLJm

This is nothing exciting but a nice idea and working very nicely without the need of any bloated code or (js) script.
However, one thing is bothering me a bit- opening an image it always triggers the back function of the browser, which is a bit annoying, because using the back button after clicking through images just re-opens the images instead of going back to the page before. Not surprising considering it's using links though.

Basically it's just opening image links like this:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li id="slide1"><img src="lw1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

and is showing them in a flex container.

But is there a way to suppress the back button event there? I am sure there must be ways using javascript but I'd love to stay on the pure html/css side if possible.
I'm afraid this is not possible, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Comment: No, it won't be possible to achieve that using just HTML and CSS. Your slider is based on clicking anchor links, and doing so adds entries to the history, that's just how it works.

Comment: Maybe using checkbox instead of anchor,  `:has(checked) + ...` to change image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<input type="radio">` to make sure only one input is checked.

Show the correct image by `.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(#{$i}):checked) + .slides div:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {...}`

**Firefox and Samsung Internet are not support!**

[image]

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  position: relative;
}

.slides div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slides div img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: top;
  object-position: top;
}

.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbnails input {
  display: block;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
}

.thumbnails input:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg");
}

.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(1):checked)+.slides div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnails input:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg");
}

.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(2):checked)+.slides div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnails input:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg");
}

.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(3):checked)+.slides div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnails input:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg");
}

.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(4):checked)+.slides div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumbnails input:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg");
}

.thumbnails:has(input:nth-of-type(5):checked)+.slides div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation: slide 1s 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=sty.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="thumbnails">
            <input type="radio" name="thumbnail" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="thumbnail">
            <input type="radio" name="thumbnail">
            <input type="radio" name="thumbnail">
            <input type="radio" name="thumbnail">
        </label>
  <div class="slides">
    <div><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" alt="lw1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" alt="lw2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" alt="lw3.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" alt="lw4.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" alt="lw5.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, that's an unexpected solution. Very nice, thanks!